# отсутствует DMARC запись

Tags: php, smtp

Проверял почту, с которой приходят письма с регистрацией на  https://www.mail-tester.com/, в результате показало, что отсутствует запись DMARC, но я не понимаю куда и как её добавить. Вот как формируются письма при отправке:

```
$server_bot = 'smtp.sgls5.a2hosting.com';
            $password_bot = '1111111';
            $mail_bot = 'no-reply@1111111.com';
            $name_bot = '11111111';
            $title = '111111111';
            $mess = '11111111111:';
            $mess1 = '111111111111';
            //SETTINGS//

            include_once('db.php');
            include_once('inc.class.php');
            $SETTINGS = new SETTINGS();
            $FORM = new FORM();
            $AUTH = new     

            $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
            $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
            $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
            $tm = time();
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//Всё для бота отправки сообщ
            $mail_class = new EMAIL($email_bot); //Создаём экземпляр класса
            $mail_class->setFromName($name_bot); //Устанавливаем имя в обратном адресеc
            $mailSMTP = new SMTP_EMAIL($server_bot, $mail_bot, $password_bot, $name_bot, 25); // создаем экземпляр класса
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
            $headers .= "From: ".$name_bot." <".$mail_bot." >\r\n"; // от кого письмо
```

Comment: https://habr.com/company/mailru/blog/170957/

Answer (score 0):

DMARC прописывается не в скриптах, а в ДНС вашего домена.
Добавьте там TXT запись следующего вида:

```
 _dmarc.site.com = "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:admin@site.com"
```

где site.com - ваш домен. admin@site.com - электронный адрес, на который будут отправляться отчеты